# Solve three-variable system $x^2 - yz = 1,\>y^2 - xz = 2,\>z^2 - xy = 3$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I am going around in circles on this system

$$x^2 - yz = 1\\
y^2 - xz = 2\\
z^2 - xy = 3$$

I have tried a few things (below) but keep hitting a wall. I know that by adding the three equations we get:
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - xz - xy =6$. And also that:

$(x-y)^2 + (x-z)^2 + (y-z)^2 = 2x^2+2y^2+2z^2-2xy-2xz-2yz=12$

I have tried the following:
$(x-y)(x+y+z)=(x^2-yz)-(y^2-xz)=-1$
$(x-z)(x+y+z)=(x^2-yz)-(z^2-xy)=-2$
$(y-z)(x+y+z)=(y^2-xz)-(z^2-xy)=-1$

So I think it follows that $x-y=y-z$ and therefore $x-z=2(x-y)$

Substituting in:
$(x-y)^2+[2(x-y)]^2+(x-y)^2=12$
$6(x-y)^2=12$
$x-y=\sqrt{2}$
Therefore: $y-z=\sqrt{2}$ and $x-z=2\sqrt{2}$

But when I rearrange and substitute into one of the original equations, the solutions I get for x, y and z don't actually work.

$y=x-\sqrt{2}$ and $z=x-2\sqrt{2}$
Substituting into the first equation:
$x^2-(x-\sqrt{2})(x-2\sqrt{2})=1$
$x=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$
Giving $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, z=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Unfortunately, substituting these values into the three original equations only satisfies the second one. Can anyone please help?

Comment: why $x-y$ cannot be $-\sqrt 2$?

Comment: also $x^2-(x-\sqrt 2)(x-2\sqrt 2)=1\implies 3\sqrt2 x-4=1\implies x=\dfrac{5}{3\sqrt 2}$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: (Both of) @Divide1918's comment is correct, and yields a valid solution set.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track but made an algebra error (cf. $y - z$).  These are quadratic equations, so there are two solutions:

$$\left\{x\to -\frac{5}{3 \sqrt{2}},y\to \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}},z\to \frac{7}{3
   \sqrt{2}}\right\}$$

$$\left\{x\to \frac{5}{3 \sqrt{2}},y\to -\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}},z\to -\frac{7}{3
   \sqrt{2}}\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks, I blew straight past the negative solution, and made the simple multiplication mistake as well. Appreciate you pointing those out.

Comment: With 3 quadratics, why aren't there eight solutions? With $x^2=1,y^2=1,z^2=1$, you get the eight solutions $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$

Answer (score 4):

This type of the system is well known.  Its general form reads

$$x^2 - yz = a,\>\>\>y^2 - xz = b,\>\>\>z^2 - xy = c$$

and has the solutions given in the symmetric expression below

$$(x,y,z)=\pm \frac{(a^2-bc, b^2-ca, c^2 -ab)}{\sqrt{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}}
$$

So, substitute $a=1,\>b=2,\>c=3$ to obtain
$\pm(\frac{-5}{3 \sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}},\frac{7}{3
   \sqrt{2}})$.

Comment: Very interesting! Is there a reference for the derivation? Or are there terms I can search for? I spent a couple of hours searching for the equations, as well as searching for quadratic system of equations, and symmetric polynomials/Newton identities. Ultimately I found a derivation on the website Toppr using "cross-multiplication" of equations (https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-ca/question/solve-x2-yz-a2-y2-zx/), but I did not find any other reference besides this very post. No worries if there is not a reference, but I just want my research to be comprehensive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to get the solution of generic equations

$$
x^2 - yz = a \>\>\> ... (1)\\
y^2 - xz = b \>\>\> ... (2)\\
z^2 - xy = c \>\>\> ... (3)
$$

I'm gonna use basic algebra to solve this, it's a little tedious but we get the answer.

Multiply 1st equation by z, 2nd by x and 3rd by y. Then add three equations to get
$$0 = az + bx + cy \>\>\> ... (4)$$

Similarly, again, Multiply the 1st equation by y, 2nd by z and 3rd by x. Then add three equations to get
$$0 = bz + cx + ay \>\>\> ... (5)$$

Now use equations (4) & (5) to eliminate 1 variable from it. let's say we get rid of z. To do that, We use a traditional approach.

Multiply equation (4) by b and equation (5) by a, And then subtract to get

$$b^2x + bcy - acx + ya^2 = 0$$
$$(b^2-ac)x + (bc-a^2)y = 0$$
$$y = \frac{b^2 - ac}{a^2 - bc} x \>\>\>  ... (6)$$

At this point, we have a value of y in terms of x

Similarly, we can get a value of z in terms of x from equations (4) & (5) by eliminating y.

$$z = \frac{c^2-ab}{a^2-cb} x \>\>\> ... (7)$$

put values of y and z in equation (1) to get the value of x in terms of a,b & c.

$$x^2 - \frac{b^2 - ac}{a^2 - bc} x * \frac{c^2-ab}{a^2-cb} x = a$$
$$x^2(1 - \frac{b^2 - ac}{a^2 - bc} * \frac{c^2-ab}{a^2-cb}) = a$$
$$x^2\frac{(a^2 - bc)^2 - (b^2 - ac)(c^2-ab)}{(a^2 - bc)^2 } = a$$
$$x^2\frac{a(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc)}{(a^2 - bc)^2 } = a$$
$$x^2 = \frac{(a^2 - bc)^2}{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc}$$

y & z can be calculated from equations (6) & (7) or we can be a little smart to observe the symmetry and get the value of y & z without calculating.

Comment: The entire system is symmetrical, and a permutation in $(a,b,c)$ corresponds to the same in $(x,y,z).$ $\therefore $ you have all $3$ solutions already by obtaining the expression for $x.$